# iOS, swift, scenekit, scene loaded event

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have set up a complex scene in SceneKit.

It takes a few seconds after viewDidLoad to show the Scene.

Is there a simple way to find if the scene is ready and displayed?
(for example to hide the "loading"-dialog)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have a look at `SCNSceneRenderer.delegate` and `-renderer:didRenderScene:atTime:`